Merge deeply nested arrays in aggregation
This is a follow-up from How to filter a nested array at the projection stage?.
After finding the relevant documents with $match, I've been asked to output only some elements of an array deep inside (that were used in the match condition). There's an array-object-array-object-array hierarchy:
db.collection.insertMany([
  { "person": [
      { "name": "joe",
        "empl": [
          { "name": "joe_e0",
            "job": [
              { "id": "joe_e0_j0", "go": "Y" },
              { "id": "joe_e0_j1", "go": "N" } ]}]}]},
  { "person": [
      { "name": "amy",
        "empl": [
          { "name": "amy_e0",
            "job": [
              { "id": "amy_e0_j0", "go": "Y" },
              { "id": "amy_e0_j1", "go": "N" } ]}]}]},
  { "person": [
      { "name": "tom",
        "empl": [
          { "name": "tom_e0",
            "job": [
              { "id": "tom_e0_j0", "go": "N" },
              { "id": "tom_e0_j1", "go": "N" },
              { "id": "tom_e0_j2", "go": "N" } ]}]}]}
]);

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {"person.empl.job.go": "Y"} },
  {
    $set: {
      person: {
        $map: {
          input: "$person",
          as: "p",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$p",
              {
                "empl": {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$p.empl",
                    as: "e",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$e",
                        {
                          "job": {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$e.job",
                              as: "j",
                              cond: { $eq: ["$$j.go","Y"] }
                            }
                          }}]}}} // empl
              }]}}} // person
  }}
]);

This produces the output I want, bringing the original objects and filtering person.empl.job:
[
  { "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "dept": "d0",
    "person": [
      { "empl": [
          { "job": [
              { "go": "Y", "id": "joe_e0_j0" }],
            "name": "joe_e0" }],
        "name": "joe" }]},
  { "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "dept": "d1",
    "person": [
      { "empl": [
          { "job": [
              { "go": "Y", "id": "amy_e0_j0" }],
            "name": "amy_e0"}],
        "name": "amy" }]}
]

Mongo playground
But,

Do I really have to alternate $map and $mergeObjects to descend this object and keep everything but my filtered array? Is there a simpler/more efficient way?
The actual condition on person.empl.job is considerably more complex, and I have to state it both in $match and later in $filter. Is there a way to avoid this?


if your person array and empl array also has more than 1 element you will have to go with the $map s

but if you want to keep all fields and not add new fields you may not need mergeObjects https://mongoplayground.net/p/-S7wVe_PkQa. regarding the match it helps to narrow down the docs that is needed to process in the next stage. so having it in both places is okay

if you dont mention the match stage you will end up with an extra element with empty job array. so you'll have to add an extra stage to remove docs with empty job array. this is bad since it goes through your whole collection and not just the ones which has a job with go===Y

Depending of context/language in which you'll use this aggregation, you should be able to put your twice-used condition in a variable, for more readability and reuse it in match and filter.
More of that, there's another way to do this, by using the $redact stage.
It's a little bit more readable, but i did not performances analysis on that.
Here's the code for your case :
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "person.empl.job.go": "Y"
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $or: [
            {
              $ne: [
                "$person",
                undefined
              ]
            },
            {
              $ne: [
                "$name",
                undefined
              ]
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$go",
                "Y"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        then: "$$DESCEND",
        else: "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }
  }
])

The conditions on $person and $name are here only to descend into object levels.
See in action here
Hope it helps
